# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.flutter_image, PID: 32038 kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error and app crashes when I am pressing the button after compressing the image  plzz help me
Thanks in advance
this is my code

```
 onPressed: () async {
    print('Selected Item = '+'$radioItemHolder');
    if (radioItemHolder.contains('High')) {
     print('High');
     for (int i = 0;i < widget.image.length;i++) {
       var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(
         widget.image[i].identifier);
    print("path");
    print(path);
    File compressedFile =await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(path, quality: 
    90);
    images.add(compressedFile);                                         
    GallerySaver.saveImage(compressedFile.path, albumName: 'Image Resizer')
     .then((bool success) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Image saved to gallary",toastLength: 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
     });
    
    }
    Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Share_Convert_Iamge(image: 
    images)),
  );
}}
```

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: You getting error after file compressing or on compression phase?

Comment: after compression when navigating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, download this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/common_utils

Then try to force wait for the compression to complete, before running the navigation logic. Just do this:

```
            import 'package:common_utils/common_utils.dart';
         
       ///.........
        Future runImageCompressionLogic() async {
            for (int i = 0;i < widget.image.length;i++) {
                         
              var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(
                         widget.image[i].identifier);
                    print("path");
                    print(path);
                    await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(path, quality: 
                    90).then((compressedFile) {
                        
                    if (!TextUtil.isEmpty(compressedFile)) {
                         images.add(compressedFile);                                         
                         GallerySaver.saveImage(compressedFile.path, 
                      albumName: 'Image Resizer')
                     .then((bool success) {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Image saved to 
                          gallary",toastLength: 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                          timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16.0);
                         });
                     });
                      }     
                     }   
                   }
               }
            
            ///.....
            
               onPressed: () async {
                    print('Selected Item = '+'$radioItemHolder');
                    if (radioItemHolder.contains('High')) {
                     print('High');
                    
                     runImageCompressionLogic().whenComplete((){
            
                         Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
                              Share_Convert_Iamge(image: 
                            images)),
                         }); 
                     );
                   }}
```